# async waterfall final callback got function not found

Tags: node.js

The error that I got was, `cb is not a function`. But as seen in this code, in the final callback of async waterfall, I have called the `cb` but still getting the error.

```
function shiftIndex(key, cb) {
  async.waterfall([
    (readFileCallback) => {
      jsonfile.readFile(dataPath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return readFileCallback(err, null, null);
        else if (!data) return readFileCallback(new Error('File Empty'), null, null);
        else return readFileCallback(null, data, key)
      });
    },

    (data, key, stackCallback) => {
      console.log("The KEY is -> " + key);
      if (!(key in data)) return stackCallback(new Error("Invalid key"), null);
      else{
        var items = data[key]
        var first = items.shift();
        items.push(first);
        return stackCallback(null, data);
      }
    },

    (data, writeDataCallback) => {
      jsonfile.writeFile(dataPath, data, (e) => {
        if (e) return writeDataCallback(e, false, null);
        else return writeDataCallback(null, true, data);
      })
    }
  ],

  (e, success, data) => {
    if (e) return cb(e, false, null);
    return cb(null, true, data);
  }
)}
```

Comment: Check that you pass function to `shiftIndex`.

Comment: how would I check that? This is the first time I've written async waterfall

Comment: `function shiftIndex(key, cb) { console.log(cb)` must print 'Function'. In this case you can avoid use async library.

Comment: @AikonMogwai Just tried that, It is a function. and may i ask why was my post got down a down vote? (Not directing the question to you Aikon, just wonder where could I improve my post

Answer (score 1):

`err, res, data` is uncommon format of callback because res is unnecessary. You always check `if (data)` instead of `if (res)`. I simplify code. Imho, it's more readable.

```
function shiftIndex(key, cb) {
    jsonfile.readFile(dataPath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) 
            return cb(err);

        if (!data)  
            return cb(new Error('File Empty'));

        if (!(key in data))
            return cb(new Error('Invalid key'));

        var items = data[key]
        var first = items.shift();
        items.push(first);
        data = items;

        jsonfile.writeFile(dataPath, data, (err) => cb(err, (err) ? null : data));
    });
};
```

Comment: yes that certainly true, i don't really need response on success, since if its a false data would be empty or null anyway. And Just a followup, my problem has been resolved now (by a simple computer restart) I do not know what cause the error. The only change I made to the project was to check whether 'cb' is a function or not, as you suggested earlier